# c++ function make_scrambled_password in mysql to mariadb

Tags: c++, mysql, mariadb

i have the simple problem with mariadb i convert my sql from the mysql to mariadb

but i have the problem in this function make_scrambled_password not exist in mariadb plz help me and this is code c++

```
std::string mysql_hash_password(const char* tmp_pwd)
{
    char hash_buf[2*SHA1_HASH_SIZE + 2] = "";
    make_scrambled_password(hash_buf, tmp_pwd);
    return hash_buf;
}
```

how to edit this in c++ code to make his compatibly with mariadb
 ..........................................

Comment: Looks like `make_scrambled_password` is an internal function that was accidentally exposed and should never have been used see: https://jira.mariadb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MDEV-13464

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function to mariadb

```
std::string mysql_hash_password(const char* tmp_pwd)
{
    char hash_buf[2*SHA1_HASH_SIZE + 2] = "";
    ma_make_scrambled_password(hash_buf, tmp_pwd);
    return hash_buf;
}
```